# How do I get the latest version of the eslint plugin from vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, plugins, eslint

If I download the eslint plugin, it will continue to download to the previous version.
I want to download the latest eslint plugin.
Why does this happen?
How do I get the latest version of the eslint plugin from vscode?

Before installation:
[image]

After installation:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try installing an extension from the command line by using the full extension name as an argument:

`code --install-extension dbaeumer.vscode-eslint`

You could also use `--force` to avoid prompts.

Alternatively, you could click on the gear icon in the extensions panel and select `Install Another Version` and select the specific version you want.

You should reload vscode if it is open after installing.